# Access between layered network routers

Tags: router, lan, wan

I have 2 standard network routers (both DHCP-enabled), one behind the other as below:

```
 WAN -->  Router A (192.168.1.1) --> Router B (192.168.100.1)
```

Router B's WAN is connected to one of Router A's LAN ports.  I can access the internet on all devices without problems.

If I have a computer connected to Router B (let's 192.168.100.7), how can I have it access Router A's admin webpage, or any computer on the Router A LAN network?

Comment: I don't have the hardware to try this out, but you should be able to access `192.168.1.*` directly unless your router is configured to hide internal addresses.

Comment: @asynts You are right. I finally figured out that I had AP (Access Point) isolation on, so I couldn't access Router A